# What to use as an address when applying for a UK EEA family permit?

Tags: visas, uk, eu-citizens

We are filling up EEA FP application at Visa4uk and have confusion regarding stay.
Below is the question in the form "What is the main address and contact details of where you will be staying whilst in the UK?"

We both are applying from outside UK and will be travelling together. We need to book hotel for Stay and looking for suggestions and advise on the below?

1. For how long period do we need to book?
2. If there is a temporary booking with pay at hotel option , would that create any issue with the UKVI. Does UKVI validate with the hotel?
3. Any other option apart from Hotel? where temporary stay is available?
   Appreciate all your inputs.

Comment: They're not really supposed to be asking about your accommodation details at all, since the issue of the permit does not depend on any condition related to accommodation.  What do you mean you're "both" applying from outside the UK?  Do you mean that you and your sponsor are outside the UK? It's confusing because the sponsor doesn't apply for anything.

Comment: @phoog thanks for your response. Sorry for the confusion, I am EEA national in this case and my husband is non EEA.

Answer (score 2):

> For how long period do we need to book?

A booking should not be required.  The permit should be granted even if you write "not yet decided" or the like.  But the UK has been known to refuse EEA family permits improperly.  If you want to play it safe, you can make a reservation for the duration of your intended stay.

> If there is a temporary booking with pay at hotel option , would that create any issue with the UKVI. Does UKVI validate with the hotel?

It should not matter whether you have paid for the booking.  The UK should not validate with the hotel.  But they might do so, so above all you should not lie.

> Any other option apart from Hotel? where temporary stay is available?

If you are visiting a friend or relative, you can list the friend or relative's home.  But don't do that unless you actually plan th stay there.